# Хранение в базе данных

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Задача следующая:
Есть таблица `nap` (общая точка доступа и хранения информации).
Есть алгоритмы:
1. В процессе
2. Выполнено
Которые решаются по `exec` столбику.
А при выводе проверяется, через условие `WHERE`: `выполнено` или `в процессе` и падают в соответствующий раздел.

Как быть?:

- Сделать отдельную таблицу для выполненных?
- Лучше если будет все в одной таблице `nap`?

Знатоки, пожалуйста подскажите, как делаете вы, когда данных очень много?
И стоит-ли, беспокоиться, что это все будет в одной таблице?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Лучше одна таблица. В ней поле Status тип поля Enum(В процессе, Выполнено). Соответственно выборка данных по условию Where Status = 'нужный статус или его порядковый номер'

Comment: Точно не `enum`, а `tinyint`, пока оставляю в одной, индексы также все настроены. Я просто сомневался, что выдержит - данных битком уже, по этому задумался.